# How to hide column in Datatable LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

I build my columns based on this query :

```
export const caseFieldSelector = "CaseNumber,IncidentSuivi__c,OwnerId,Subject,Status,Owner.name,AccountId,Account.Name,Interaction_client__c,Date_ouverture__c,ContactId,Contact.Name,Priority,Type,Produit__c,Environnement__c,SiteForPortal__c,Developpement__c,CorrectionsReports__c,Nom_du_groupement__c,Date_fermeture__c";
```

Here's how i build columns

```
  this.fieldsForCloumn = items.map(field => this.columns[field] != undefined? this.columns[field] : {label : field , fieldName : field});
```

HTML

```
 <lightning-datatable data={cases} columns={fieldsForCloumns} key-field="Id" sorted-by={sortedBy} 
            sorted-direction={sortedDirection} 
            onsort={onSort} ></lightning-datatable>
```

[image]

I want to not display some columns like Incident .. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```js
const fieldsToNotDisplay = ['IncidentSuivi__c'];

this.fieldsForCloumn = items
   .filter(field => !fieldsToNotDisplay.includes(field))
   .map(field => (this.columns[field] || {label: field , fieldName: field}));
```

Comment: i want to get datatable columns as options in the  `<lightning-dual-listbox` ..

Comment: You need to pass columns as `options={options}`.

Comment: can't achieve it , when i add lookup field to dual box it throws an error : *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name'* because i set up the field in Wire method like this : `wiredMethod(result) {
            if(data) {
                this.cases = result.data.map(record => {
                    record = {...record};
                    if(record.ContactId != null){
                    record.ContactId = record.Contact.Name;}`